# Cronjobs not executing php scripts, no mailto warnings received!

Tags: php, cron

Here's my situation:

I'm trying to run a php script via cron, and I've got a crontab (/etc/crontab) that looks like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/var/www:
MAILTO=<myemailaddress>

m h dom mon dow user  command

*  *    * * *   root    /usr/bin/php /var/www/testing.php
```

And when I run the command `/usr/bin/php /var/www/testing.php` from bash/sh, everything is dandy. It's just a basic php script that writes some gibberish to a file. However, my cronjob is not executing. I've used sudo service cron restart several times but all to no avail. Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks, and cheers!

**Solution**

My own fault! The php script I was running was writing to a file that was not properly accessed - e.g., lacking full file paths. Thanks for the help all!

Comment: Do you have a blank line right after your rule in the cronjob file?

Comment: My actual cron table begins and ends with '#', where the closing pound sign is on its own line after my code snippet right there. That is the EOF.

Comment: edit:: Guess last comment disappeared, as for the OS it's just Ubuntu. This is the master crontab, not an individual user's -- that is, it lives in /etc/crontab. The user-specific crontabs do not have a user column.

Comment: Yes -- I just did `* * * * * root echo hi >> /tmpnonsense` and it worked. Every minute it appended hi.

Comment: I'm also having success with `/usr/bin/php -r 'echo file_get_contents("/tmp/nonsense");' >> /tmp/omg` so it's having no problem using php -- and this: `/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/testing.php` is the snippet that is causing me grief. I've tried with/without the -f flag. Oyy!!

Comment: `<?php $file = "testfile"; file_put_contents($file, "it worked!"); ?>` My understanding was that -r was necessary only for direct php (e.g., untagged) parsing? AAAAND it works now. I'm a fool -- `$file = "testfile" has to be "/var/www/testfile". It was trying to create the testfile wherever cron was running this from. D'oh... Thank you for your help @mu is too short!

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a shell script and put the PHP command in there. Make it executeabl and put it into the crontab.

You can then better track and change the command as well as setting up the environment (vars, paths) for the php script more easily.